# OpenDaylight BGP

Tags: opendaylight, bgp

Version: OpenDaylight Boron SR3 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

I started playing with OpenDaylight BGP but I cannot bring up TCP session between ODL and router.

ODL IP: 10.1.1.10
Router IP: 10.1.1.1

I have edited 41-bgp-example.xml as follows:

```
<module>
 <type xmlns:prefix="urn:opendaylight:params:xml:ns:yang:controller:bgp:rib:impl">prefix:bgp-peer-acceptor</type>
    <name>bgp-peer-server</name>
    <!--Default parameters-->
    <binding-address>10.1.1.10</binding-address>
    <!--Default binding-port 179-->
    <binding-port>179</binding-port>
</module>

<module>
 <type xmlns:prefix="urn:opendaylight:params:xml:ns:yang:controller:bgp:rib:impl">prefix:bgp-peer</type>
 <name>example-bgp-peer</name>
 <host>10.1.1.1</host>
 <holdtimer>180</holdtimer>
 <retrytimer>10</retrytimer>
 <peer-role>ibgp</peer-role>
</module>

<module>
 <type xmlns:prefix="urn:opendaylight:params:xml:ns:yang:controller:bgp:rib:impl">prefix:rib-impl</type>
 <name>example-bgp-rib</name>
 <rib-id>example-bgp-rib</rib-id>
 <local-as>100</local-as>
 <bgp-rib-id>10.1.1.10</bgp-rib-id>
</module>
```

Restarted ODL many times. When I run tcpdump, I see ODL is sending a TCP RST to the router when the router attempts to start a TCP session. There is connectivity between ODL and router - ping works. I have disabled IPTables too. Running ODL as root. I have debug enabled for BGP.

log display shows no output for BGP.

```
opendaylight-user@root>log:display | grep BGP
opendaylight-user@root>
```

Are there any more changes required?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it turned out the features were not installed properly.

Re-installed features and it works now.